# C#: I want to pass messages like a file path to my forms application like a console application, how would I do that?

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line, arguments

C#: I want to pass messages like a file path to my forms application like a console application, how would I do that?

I was told I needed to find my main method to add string[] args, but I wouldn't know which one that would be in Windows Forms. Which would my main method be in C# windows forms application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() is a better option. But I will keep the following answer as an alternative to it.

Look for a file called Program.cs containing the following code fragment...

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

and change that to

```
static class Program
{

    public static string[] CommandLineArgs { get; private set;}

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CommandLineArgs = args;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Then access the command line args from your form ...

```
Program.CommandLineArgs
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Main()` method is located in `Program.cs` file, typically like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

You should modify the `Main()` to the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

You'll have access to the arguments passed.

Also, you could access the arguments using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get access to the command line parameters, use Environment.CommandLine

```
string args = Environment.CommandLine;
```

You can do this whether or not you have a main method with string[] args in your code.

Answer (score 2):

There's one `Main()`, which is inside `Program.cs`. But in WinForms app `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` will be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

in your public constructor, use the following:

string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

this will give you a string array of the arguments.